# I need more obstacles for my characters to reach the goal. Any ideas?

Tags: fiction, fantasy, writers-block

I have a group of characters hunting for a precious item.
I want my characters to have problems reaching the item, problems that come in the way before they can get to it. I can give an example. Firstly, troops of antagonist appear to fend them off. These sorts of occurances, not that the item just keeps going further away.
However, I am unable to think up ways in which I can arch out problems. Like, use the characters flaws, in a way? I need more ideas. Please suggest.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I'm afraid that idea-generation questions like this are off-topic here. We can give you advice on *how* to plan or write your story, but we're not going to create or write the plot for you.